# Problem connecting to Github with SSH in WSL

Tags: github, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-keys

I want to connect to github using SSH protocol in my WSL, i followed every single step from the github documentation [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh).
The key was generated, I've tested my connection, but it still doesn't work. I still have to put username or password everytime i push my code to github. Can anyone help me on this?

I also did this.

```
# start the ssh-agent in the background
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
> Agent pid 59566

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

PS: I don't know if this is related or not, but I have two .ssh directories in my WSL and my bash root folder.
It works in my bash because i guess VS Code generated the SSH key for me.

[image: Above is my SSH in WSL, and below is my SSH in bash (and this one is working)]

Edit:
I guess it's the ssh-agent that's not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're being prompted for a username and password, it's possible that you're trying to use the HTTPS protocol instead of SSH.  You can see what the URL looks like by using `git remote -v`.  If you want to change to use the SSH protocol, you'd use something like `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:git/git.git` (where `git/git.git` is the repository you're pushing to).

In general, trying to connect to GitHub over SSH won't prompt you for a username and password, because GitHub doesn't support password authentication over SSH.

Answer (score 6):

On WSL 2, I was using SSH to commit to GitHub and found that I was asked for my password every time. After hours of searching and trying several methods (which worked with caveats I couldn't live with), this is what worked for me.

Install [keychain](https://funtoo.org/Keychain):

```
sudo apt install keychain
```

Then add the following line to your shell's configuration file (likely `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`):

```
eval `keychain --quiet --eval --agents ssh id_rsa`
```

Now you will only have to enter your password when booting WSL!

Credit to Birk Holland with [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/sharing-ssh-keys-between-windows-and-wsl-2/).

Answer (score 1):

This is followed by [eamodio/vscode-gitlens issue 909](https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/909)

> I am trying to use git through SSH in a WSL remote.
>   The SSH connection is protected with a key pair which is password-protected.
>   How do I start an SSH agent and input that passphrase for a shell in which GitLens operates?
>
> By default a bash/wsl shell is opened in terminal window on WSL remote connection.
>   **I start an SSH agent there and add the key, but it seems like this is not the shell in which GitLens is sending its git commands**.

A workaround would be to regenerate those keys (after opening first a session with the existing keys) and:

- make sure the new keys are not passphrase-protected
- add the new public one in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file of the WSL session.

Comment: thanks! it didn't work before because i cloned the repo using HTTPS now it does